# Dirac Delta special case

Tags: functional-analysis, special-functions, dirac-delta

How can we define a generalized function, very similar with Dirac Delta, that is zero on the real line but 1 at 0 (origin), instead of "infinity"?

Something without using piecewise notation?

I'm looking for something that I can use with Mathematica to inspect some properties on the real numbers.

If possible I would some help to define this function on Mathematica too.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematica has a function called [`DiscreteDelta`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscreteDelta.html) for such purposes:

> `DiscreteDelta[0]` gives $1$; `DiscreteDelta[n]` gives $0$ for other numeric $n$.